# Python venv returns error message. How to create a venv on windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, virtualenv

Every time I try to create a virtualenv for my Python project in VSCode and CommandPrompt using:

`python -m venv venv`

I get this error message:

`Error: Command '['D:\\Coding Projects\\VS Code\\Ca$hTraCK\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 2.`

I tried disabling and enabling python extension, upgrading pip version, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your python version, but if you're in Anoconda python, use command

`python -m venv --without-pip venv`

to create, cause Anoconda doesn't have ensurepip, then install pip after you activate the venv.

Also, python3.3 and higher version support venv module.

If the command doesn't work, it's recommended to reinstall python from [[download]](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: I am using Python 8.3 on Windows. I am also not using Anaconda. ```python -m venv --without-pip venv ``` works, but does that means I cannot use pip in venv?

Comment: u can still use pip in theory, but if not, you should install it. have you tried?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. Seems like pip is still working although some modules i installed using pip doesn't work with intellisense in VSCode.

Comment: Edit: I think I fixed it. I uninstalled, and reinstalled the latest version of Python, and checked Add Python to PATH before installation. Retried making a venv on cmd, and it works with no errors. Thanks.